# Exception in thread java programming error

Tags: java

I am trying to run a java program to find if number is palindrome or not but at the time of compilation i am getting error message as - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: This method must return result of type Boolean.

below is my program code :

```
package testing;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PalindromeNumber { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number to check if it is palindrome or not :");
        int number1 = new Scanner (System.in).nextInt();
        if(PalindromeCheck(number1)) {
            System.out.println("Number " +number1+ " is palindrome.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Number " + number1 + " is not palindrome.");
        }
    }




public static boolean PalindromeCheck(int number) {
    int palindrome = number;
    int reverse = 0;
    while (palindrome !=0) {
        int remainder = palindrome % 10;
        reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
        palindrome = palindrome / 10;
        if (number == reverse) {
            return true;
        }

    return false;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Put one of the 3 ending curlybraces before the Line 'return false;'

Comment: Thanks @Pras. It worked. can you please tell me what my mistake was ?

Comment: From what I see it doesn't look like you're working in an IDE. While I can't force you to, I do recommend you switch to one. An IDE can resolve and identify problems for you, as well as provide suggestions to help you code faster.

Comment: Your mistake was failing to include a required ending brace in the correct place, followed by ignoring a compiler error message and attempting to execute the resulting invalid class.  As @WinterRoberts says, use an IDE, Eclipse or NetBeans if you want a free one.

Comment: The curly brace i asked u to move is the "end" of while loop : you were returning false in the loop actually

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean PalindromeCheck(int number) {
    int palindrome = number;
    int reverse = 0;
    while (palindrome !=0) {
        int remainder = palindrome % 10;
        reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
        palindrome = palindrome / 10;
        if (number == reverse) {
            return true;
        }

    return false;
}
}
}
```

In this case, while loop also includes return false. So, in the case when while loop is completed , you don't have a return value. So, the following will work:

```
public static boolean PalindromeCheck(int number) {
    int palindrome = number;
    int reverse = 0;
    while (palindrome !=0) {
        int remainder = palindrome % 10;
        reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
        palindrome = palindrome / 10;
        if (number == reverse) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Priyansh Goel

Comment: @AkshayJadhav : Please accept the answer <Click on tick to accept>

Answer (score 1):

What if the number=0 at the begining? Your code won't return anything at that moment. Return false, outside the while loop.

```
public static boolean PalindromeCheck(int number) {
    int palindrome = number;
    int reverse = 0;
    while (palindrome !=0) {
        int remainder = palindrome % 10;
        reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
        palindrome = palindrome / 10;
        if (number == reverse) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; //Note the curly brace above. Now the method will always return either true or false
}
```